# How to add likelihoods of something happening (probabilities)

Tags: probability

let's say there's an event "A". I know that on cloudy nights(observation 1) event "A" has a 62% chance of happening, I also know that on full moons(observation 2) event "A" has a 60% chance happening.

What is the chance of event "A" happening when it is both a cloudy night and a full moon?

The observations are completely independent of one another. Is there a way to calculate the new probability of event A happening given what we know about the observations?

Comment: Not enough information.  Maybe it never happens on a cloudy night with a full moon; maybe it always does.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).